# Timeout/Sleep in NightWatch/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timeout, nightwatch.js

How to input between lines of code some force-timeout (like java Thread.Sleep)  in NighWatch.js ?
Have to wait for element to have exact value after page render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to stop the thread since javascript is single thread non blocking.
What you want to do is this

setInterval(function () {alert("Hello")}, 3000);
The syntax is.

window.setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);

See : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 22):

I don't think this is the correct answer. For the original poster it's probably too late but other users might google it:

If you use the Nightwatch testing frame work then you can use these commands:
http://nightwatchjs.org/api#pause
browser.pause(1000); // pauses the test for 1000 milliseconds

or wait for an element to be present:

browser.waitForElementPresent('body', 1000); // waits max. 1000 ms for the element to appear

Comment: This should be the correct answer in regards to the original question within the context of Nightwatch. Setting a setInterval in your test script will indeed delay the script found within, but won't delay the completion of the given test. Using browser.pause will do what your are looking for.